# How to use UI with Stereoscopic videos in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, stereoscopy, 360-virtual-reality

I have to develop 360 experience in Virtual Reality Stereoscopic in Unity

When adding a UI to the Stereoscopic experience in Unity, it appears as if I have two UI's in the scene.

To solve this problem, I created two UI's with two cameras in the scene, the left camera can see the UI masked with the left layer, and the right camera can see the UI masked with the right layer.

And there are other issues I am facing as well with the POINTER in the Motion Controllers specifically. It starts with straight single line, and then splits into two lines.

this method of solving this issue is very tedious and takes a lot of time, and I have been given short time to implement 360 experience at my workspace. Therefore, I am looking for alternative ways that can be used to solve this issue.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the the canvas to world space attached to the front o the camera?

Flat 2D elements taking up fixed screen dimensions don't translate over to a "true" 3D view. You need to make the 2D element exist in 3D space rather than as an overlay.

Comment: Yes, my canvas is set to world space. Even the pointer from the controllers are which considered to be 3D objects is shown as two lines